# convert 3D list to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to convert a 3D list to a numpy array.

When i am trying to do that using np.array(list) or np.asarray(list) it is giving 2D numpy array of shape (6,10).

How can I get numpy array of 3 dimensional(like shape should be (6,10,10). Can someone help me resolving this issue.

The list i am trying to convert is mentioned below

```
[[[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]]
[[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L] [4L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]]
[[0L, 1L, 2L] [0L, 1L, 2L] [0L, 1L, 2L] [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]]
[[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]]
[[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L] [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L] [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L] [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]]
[[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
[0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you build a 2D list and convert it to numpy with `np.array()` it will return a numpy array with 2 dimensions.

If you build a 3D list and convert it to numpy with `np.array()` it will return a numpy array with 3 dimensions.

Minimal working example:

```
my_list = [[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]],[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]]
my_list
```

> [[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]]

```
my_np_array = np.array(my_list)
my_np_array.shape
```

> (2, 2, 3)

Answer (score 1):

That's because this is not a 3D list. List has format [item,item]; 2D list would be [[],[]]. There are no inner level separators(',') in the file above. Load it into python and you get a 6,10 tuple back, the first valid entry after which no commas, so error out.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not a homogeneous list, so it gives error when creating you matrix. Each dimension that u create must be equal size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).